# Не работает offset

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Zабор</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
   <script src="https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?146" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <header>
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                  <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Форум</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Фотогаллерея</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Акции</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Конкурсы</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Woman</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Хочу что бы меню по центру была выровнена.

Comment: лучше обернуть navbar-nav в блок с классом col-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`offset-lg-2` замените на `col-lg-offset-2`

Пример

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Форум</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Фотогаллерея</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Акции</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Конкурсы</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Woman</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я пробовал, не помогает, не добавляется отступ почему то